# Flyway in Multi Module Maven Project and Running migration script together at start of the build

Tags: maven, flyway

I have a maven multi module (EAR) project in the following structure

```
Parent-Proj
+-- ear-proj
+-- war-proj
+-- java-projA
|    +--src/main/resources/db/migration/ scripts for proj A
+-- java-projB
|    +--src/main/resources/db/migration/ scripts for proj B
+-- java-projC
|    +--src/main/resources/db/migration/ scripts for proj C
```

Usually we do migration using spring flyway integration that works perfectly on server start, but here the problem is we want to run flyway migration from maven build but not independently but as an aggregate (means projA+projB+projC migration scripts) before child module build. Is it possible using maven to aggreate and run flyway script at the start of the build.

Comment: Why would you want this? And does "before build" mean before the `package` phase? What database would you run the migrations against?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i required the DB to be migrated at once and that also before first module's junit start running. Not exactly at package phase but while resource-copy or before unit test

Comment: Normally you do not run tests that require database at the unit test phase. For many reasons. One of them is that the integration phase has pre- and post- hooks at maven where you normally apply your migrations to the database.

Comment: @MykolaGurov thats true, but with our current code infrastructure some unit test more or less work like an integration test too :-) . This migration doesn't work with pre post hooks like i mentioned Project A depends on Project B, so when we build Project A it should pick migration script from Project B too.

Comment: Executing a test during the integration-test phase is simply a matter of renaming it from *Test.java to *IT.java (granted standard setup). Add a test dependency from A to B to hint maven about the proper order.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but the matter is not that easy to add A to B dependency because code in B depends on A, is there anyway to say only some resource in A depends on B, C like that.